# Counter in for loop always prints 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, lychrel-numbers

I need to check if a number is Lychrel number and if not to print the number of times the loop did until it got to the palindrome, for some reason it always print 0

```
    num = input('please enter your number ')
num = int(num)
count = 0
for i in range(1, 500):
    if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
        print(count)
        exit()
    else:
        num = num + int(str(num)[::-1])
        count += 1
print('True')
```

update: thanks to Vova the code is now working.
fixed code:

```
    num = int(input('please enter your number '))
count = 0
for i in range(1, 500):
    if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
        print(count)
        exit()
    else:
        num = num + int(str(num)[::-1])
        count += 1
print('True')
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: User input, it can be any integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will print 0 each time when you type 1 numeric number(0..9)

When you type more than 1 numeric not mirror number for example 2,3,4 etc(10,234 etc), it will print 1

Moreover it will never print True, coz you exit() it in if statement

Try to input 23, it will print 1:

```
num = int(input('please enter your number '))
count = 0
for i in range(1, 500):
    if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
        print(count)
        exit()
    else:
        num = num + int(str(num)[::-1])
        count += 1
print('True')
```

Comment: For some reason it never print anything that is not 0

Comment: still it prints 0
please enter your number 23
0

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: thank you, after i changed the code and closed pycharm and reopen it works